# Can I insert data into table in Hive similar as in SQL?

Tags: sql, hive, insert-update

I'm currently learning to use HIVE and now am trying to create tables and insert values into it. It seems that HIVE only supports insert data into the table by using "select" data from other tables or load data into the table.

Is is possible I insert or append row into HIVE similar with in SQL? Like: Insert into test values (1, 1, 1);
Seems impossible cause I tried many combinations and always returns exception as "Can't recognition XXX around XXX".

So HIVE doesn't support this type of inserting row? Do I have to load the data from external file in order to do my test (small and simple queries)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Hive don't support insert into table values format

You need to either load the data from flat file to Hive or Hive Table to Hive.

Loading from flat file can be done 2 ways, 1 from Local file system, 2 from hadoop file system.

You can actually make a join from 2 different tables and load into new table. Even overwrite is possible.

Check the links below for type of loading and formats.

http://zacktutorials.blogspot.ca/2014/07/big-data-hadoop-hive-sql-query-hello.html

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML